# Power-BI API reporting 403 unauthorized (while trying to fetch the groups) with the service principle

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-networking, azure-web-apps

Power-BI API is reporting `403 unauthorized` (while trying to fetch the groups) with the service principle.

[image: 403 forbidden]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared much to say what's happening, but does the SPN have permission to access Azure AD?

If you're using Graph to query the data, then use the SPN app registration to add read permissions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration